# GWT RPC: using methods of other Service Implementation fails

Tags: java, gwt, gwt-rpc

I get an error while calling one of my GWT services.

[image]

Eclipse console puts out this:

```
SCHWERWIEGEND: javax.servlet.ServletContext log: Exception while dispatching incoming RPC call
com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.UnexpectedException: Service method 'public abstract de.hdm.gruppe09.clickandlove.shared.report.AllInfosOfProfileReport      de.hdm.gruppe09.clickandlove.shared.ReportGenerator.createAllInfosOfProfileReport(de.hdm.gruppe09.clickandlove.shared.bo.Profil) throws java.lang.IllegalArgumentException' threw an unexpected exception: java.lang.NullPointerException
.......
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at de.hdm.gruppe09.clickandlove.server.report.ReportGeneratorImpl.createAllInfosOfProfileReport(ReportGeneratorImpl.java:107)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.agent.runtime.Runtime.invoke(Runtime.java:130)
at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.invokeAndEncodeResponse(RPC.java:561)
... 40 more
```

ReportGeneratorImpl.java:107 looks like this (107 is the first of the two Sysos):

```
103       //Abrufen des eingeloggten Profils. Wird benoetigt für die anschließende Berechnung des Aehnlichkeitsmaßes
104    Profil ep = this.verwaltung.getEingeloggtesProfil();

//Ausgaben über das ep. Nur zu Textzwecken
107       System.out.println("RGImpl: eingeloggtesProfilID:" + ep.getId());
   System.out.println("RGImpl: eingeloggtesProfilMail:" + ep.getEmail());


//Abrufen des Aehnlichkeitsmaï¿½es

int score = this.verwaltung.berechneAhnlichkeit(p, ep);
System.out.println("RGImpl: Score:" + score);
//Score Int Wert in String umwandeln, da new Column nur String Werte annimmt
String scorestring = Integer.toString(score);
//Setzen des Aehnlichkeitsmaï¿½es
Row TopRow = new Row();
TopRow.addColumn(new Column(fullname));
TopRow.addColumn(new Column(scorestring));
```

Obviously the Object ep must be null. Probably because line 104 fails.
My method fails whenever I use methods of "this.verwaltung".
Here is how I create my object of verwaltung:

```
private Verwaltung verwaltung = null;

public void init() throws IllegalArgumentException {
    VerwaltungImpl a = new VerwaltungImpl();
    a.init();
    this.verwaltung = a;
}
```

Since both the "ReportGeneratorImpl" and the VerwatlungImpl" are running on the server I understand that i need no Callbacks to use methods from one another. Is that right?

Comment: Christian, how do you login a Profil? When will eingeloggtesProfil be set?

Answer (score 0):

> Obviously the Object ep musst [sic] be null.

Have you considered starting the embedded Jetty server that GWT uses with the debugger and setting a breakpoint on line 104, so that you can step through the code and see what the cause of the `NullPointerException` is?

See *Testing Services During Development* here for more details: http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideServerCommunication.html